# Software for AI generated pictures

Tags: android, images, image-processing, image-editing

Where can I get Android software that generates AI pictures that can be used as profile pictures in antonymous accounts? I've heard this is possible, but I'm not sure where I can get such an app.

Answer (score 2):

The original is a website called [This person does not exist (Website)](https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/).

Someone wrote an Android app around that website with the same name [This person does not exist (Google Store)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trueapps.thispersondoesnotexist&hl=en). Since the website does not provide any options, neither does the app. So you have no choice for sex or age, you can just try the next generated photo.